# Keep unserializable object in application memory

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my asp.net site I'm using an third party component for every user to provide data und subsume actions. Unfortunatly the component initialization is pretty slow (about 1-2 seconds) - way too long to initialize every page request.

So I'm trying to store this object in my application. But in any way it is null after the next page request. Simple objects are working as expected, of course.

I have tried so far

- Static variables
- HttpContext.Session
- HttpContext.Cache
- TempData

In all cases my application forgets everything, but I don't get any error.

Is there any way to achieve keeping those objects in memory?

Here is my minimal example. When I exchange the values to string everything works fine. With this object, I get `null` in Login method.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public static IFrameworkItem Test;
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Test = FrameworkItem.Create("admin", "admin");
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult CreateItem(string username, string password)
    {
        var test = HomeController.Test;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Though it should work with `static`, you could host it in a Windows Service, let your web app talk to the service.

Comment: HttpContext.Session and HttpContext.Cache should remember things between requests... Are you initializing it correctly? Are the users signed in (HttpContext.Session), how are you using HttpContext.Cache?

Comment: @CodeCaster I thought about this, but since it would need a lot more (?) development, I'd rather like to solve this.

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen between requests, where I save this object. After restart I expect this behavior ;)

Comment: Could you post your code, on your preferred approach? (HttpContext.Session, HttpContext.Cache or Static Variables?)

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen So I did. Nothing special actually, but hard to understand, why asp.net keeps "forgetting" this.

Comment: I just did an example where i had a public static string, set it in one method, and got it in another. It worked fine. Does it work if you remove the complexity of your IFrameWorkItem?

Comment: @BjørnØyvindHalvorsen I cannot modify this Framework, thus I need to modify my webserver. But I also guess, this could help.
But thanks for your help, right now I guess, putting this in a Service might be the best solution so far.

Comment: I would think that to be overkill. This is a very simple thing to do, and should be figured out. To make a service for this should not be needed. It's standard lifecycle process. In my opinion you would waste a lot of time, and meet this problem further down the road again... :) Test if you can save a string in a static variable, and retrieve it again..

Comment: Yes, that's probably true. As I tried to say in my question edit, I can save a string. Also other (serializable) objects. But this specific object is not possible. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after many more hours of searching I found that this framework does logging on a file, which was not in App_Data. So I guess the ASP.NET website was restarted every time a file change was noticed.

A real bad issue, but now it is solved by forbidding this behavior.